# Are questions about Robin Hood on topic?

Tags: discussion

Robin Hood has been the subject of a number of films, cartoons and books over the years.

Prompted by [this deleted question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/78648/how-does-the-army-know-to-cheer-for-longstride?noredirect=1#comment164732_78648), given that he exists as a *fictional* character within a largely fictionalised representation of Medieval England, are questions about him (and his various media) on-topic here?

[image]

[image] [image]

Comment: To my recollection, the "Robin Hood" game from Sierra Games was the only version that had any SF/F elements.

Comment: I vote on-topic, just so we can add Men in Tights to the list of films we discusss

Comment: Does the story contain magic, robots (time-travelling or otherwise) or spaceships? I don't remember that => **off-topic**.

Comment: http://marvel.wikia.com/Robin_Hood_%28Earth-616%29

Comment: @GorchestopherH - He was suspected of being a robot in Doctor Who

Comment: Jango Fett is rumored to be his direct descendant.

Comment: @Wikis Robin Hood is a mythodology. A mythodolodgy does not need magic, robots or spaceships to be on topic here. Correct me, if I'm wrong.

Comment: @trejder - do you mean, *"mythology"*? If that is what you mean, please check out this question: [Can I ask about mythology?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5014/can-i-ask-about-mythology)

Answer (score 8):

[Robin of Sherwood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_of_Sherwood) is almost certainly **on**-topic, otherwise it's more folk legend than sci-fi/fantasy.

My gut feeling is that the proposed [Mythology.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58307/mythology) on Area 51 would be a more suitable home.  [One of its current example questions relates to King Arthur](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58307/mythology/68316#68316), for example, who is a figure of similar provenance.

Comment: Yes, Robin of Sherwood features magicians and witches on a pretty regular basis.

Comment: @Richard thanks for explaining for those of us not familiar with the series.

Comment: Then it sounds as though *Robin of Sherwood* would be on topic, but versions such as *Robin Hood: Prince of Thieves* and (unfortunately) *Men In Tights* would not.

Comment: @phantom42 - Prince of Thieves featured a witch. She seemed to have magical powers; http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xmj0v6_the-witch-from-robin-hood-prince-of-thieves-1991_shortfilms

Comment: I think her real power was the power to be so completely forgotten.

Comment: @phantom42 - She wasn't the main character, it's true.